# Non-serializable warning when passing callback in initialParams

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am facing the common situation of receiving `non-serializable values were found in the navigation state` when passing a callback within a stack's initialParams...

I have read around why this happens and I can understand it, I'm just not sure how else I should go about my logic for logging in and switching between navigator screens.

When I am not logged in it will show a simple log in screen, but once logged in it will switch to a tab navigator.

**MainNav.tsx**

```
const MainNav = () => {
   const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
   const performLogIn = () => setIsLoggedIn(true);


   return (
      <Stack.Navigator>
         {isLoggedIn
             ? <Stack.Screen name="LogIn" component={LogIn} initialParams={{performLogIn}}/>
             : <Stack.Screen name="TabNav" component={TabNav} />
         }
      </Stack.Navigator>
   );
};
```

**LogIn.tsx**

```
const LogIn = ({route: {params: {performLogIn}}}) => (
   <View>
      <Text>Log in</Text>
      <Button title="Log in" onPress={performLogIn} />
   </View>
)
```

**Account.tsx**

```
const TabNav = ({route}) => (
   <View>
      <Text>This is the logged in tab navigation main page</Text>
   </View>
)
```

Comment: Use Context, see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow for details.

Comment: @user18309290 I was hoping you wouldn't say that XD